# can't start dreamfall chapters : core dumped

Tags: games, xrandr

Ubuntu 20.04
The game "dreamfall chapters" can't start.
I see the game pointer on a blank screen and then quickly back to desktop.
Plug joystick don't change anything, neither **LC_ALL=C** or **-force-opengl**.

Terminal output:

```
$ ./Dreamfall\ Chapters
Set current directory to ~/Dreamfall.Chapters
Found path: ~/Dreamfall.Chapters/Dreamfall Chapters
Mono path[0] = '~/Dreamfall.Chapters/Dreamfall Chapters_Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = '~/Dreamfall.Chapters/Dreamfall Chapters_Data/Mono'
Mono config path = '~/Dreamfall.Chapters/Dreamfall Chapters_Data/Mono/etc'
displaymanager : xrandr version warning. 1.6
client has 4 screens
displaymanager screen (0)(DVI-0): 1280 x 1024
Using libudev for joystick management


Importing game controller configs
Abandon (core dumped)
```

Comment: A Steam game a Wine game?

Comment: Steam game. But after restart the machine today, it's ok! :o Same with another game (the first tree) freshly installed yesterday. No update or something at all! Damn.. even if it ok I would like to have an explication!